# "Unable to locate a Java Runtime" while starting kafka and zookeeper service

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to run Kafka and Zookeeper services locally on MacOS; so I am following these steps : https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

But when I am entering this command `sudo bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties` ; it is throwing this error ->

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

But I have java installed locally.

```
(base) sourav.kumar@PFIN-BLR-1RC9W kafka_2.13-3.4.0 % which java
/usr/bin/java
(base) sourav.kumar@PFIN-BLR-1RC9W kafka_2.13-3.4.0 % which javac
/usr/bin/javac
(base) sourav.kumar@PFIN-BLR-1RC9W kafka_2.13-3.4.0 % java -version
openjdk version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-44)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-44, mixed mode, sharing)
(base) sourav.kumar@PFIN-BLR-1RC9W kafka_2.13-3.4.0 % /usr/bin/java -version
openjdk version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-44)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-44, mixed mode, sharing)
(base) sourav.kumar@PFIN-BLR-1RC9W kafka_2.13-3.4.0 % javac -version
javac 19.0.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka does not support Java 19. The latest known working version for Kafka is 17. The Zookeeper documentation doesn't mention anything above JDK 12.

In any case, the error is suggesting you've not exported `JAVA_HOME` variable on your machine, or if you have, then it's pointed at the wrong location since it should otherwise fallback to running `java` directly, as you've shown

You also don't need sudo to run Kafka or Zookeeper

Comment: so what to do then? how do i run the service?

Comment: @aminaibrahim Install a supported Java version (17 at the highest). Correctly set JAVA_HOME to point at that version. Then read the Kafka documentation on the startup commands with/without Zookeeper (which do not use sudo, as that would start in a clean environment, without the JAVA_HOME variable). Homebrew or Docker also are valid ways to run Kafka on Mac/Linux